# How do I manually set the time to a UTC timestamp in Linux?

Tags: linux, date

If I want to set the time I know I can use a command like this:

```
sudo date +%T -s '17:45:00'
```

And it will set the clock to 5:45pm in the system time zone. This means that if I have the system set to UTC this will be 17:45 UTC, but if the system is set to Eastern time then the same command would actually update the clock to be 12:45 UTC. Is there some way I can specify the timezone identifier along with the time, in the `date -s` command?

Comment: What version of `date` are you using? This doesn't match the documentation of `date` that I'm reading. And why are you doing this at all?

Comment: Looks like the version is 8.2.3. It's what came installed on Raspbian.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of trial-and-error experimentation, I figured it out. To set just the time and to force it to be in UTC, I can do this:

```
sudo date +%T%Z -s "17:45:00UTC"
```

If I want to set the date and the time simultaneously, I can do this:

```
sudo date -s '2018-01-26T17:45:00Z'
```

Comment: It's all in the man page. Both `-d` and `-s` take a "date string"  and its format is described (actually a very permissive input). You can use `date -d` as a dry run for `date -s`

Answer (score 2):

In most flavors of Linux (Particularly Redhat/Centos off the top of my head), do this:

```
# Delete the current time zone file
rm -f /etc/localtime

# Set it to the new value
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

I understand that this does not use the `date` command as you requested.

Answer (score 2):

If the device you are updating the time on, does not have a connection to the internet. And you don't care about sub-seconds accuracy. You can use this on a computer with a known correct time to generate a bash command that sets the correct time using UTC timestamp.

```
echo "date +%s -s @$(date +%s)"
```

This will generate something like `date +%s -s @1541377821` that you can copy and paste to the other computer.

Comment: Underrated answer, this saved me some keystrokes :)